# Not able to update multiple rows, table being locked

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2

I'm trying to update multiple records with 'CLOSED' status wherever the column has few values.

But, it returns me

```
Error code :-913, Error message :[SQL0913] Row or object BBT_00008 in BB type *FILE in use.
```

Here is my code

```
    public void updateIdsStatus(boolean allIdCreated, List<String> ids) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, BBException {
    if(ids.size() > 0) {
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        con = DBUtil.getConnection();   
        try {               
            String sql;

            if (allIdCreated) {
                logger.info("Updating the status of the ids as CLOSED");
                sql = "UPDATE <table> SET STATUS = 'CLOSED' WHERE BBDIDNOPK IN ('"+StringUtils.join(ids, "', '")  +"') ";
            } else {
                logger.info("Updating the status of the deals as NEW");
                sql = "UPDATE <table> SET STATUS = 'NEW' WHERE BBDIDNOPK IN ('"+StringUtils.join(ids, "', '")  +"') ";
            } 
            logger.info("updateIdsStatussql :"+sql);
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info(e.getErrorCode()+"-"+e.getMessage());   
            throw new BBException (e.getErrorCode(), e.getMessage());
         } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info(e);
        } finally {
            try{    
                if(ps != null) 
                    ps.close();
                if (con != null)
                    con.close();
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                se.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The query which it prints is

```
UPDATE <table name> SET STATUS = 'CLOSED' WHERE BBDIDNOPK IN ('abc34569sf', 'abc38511hu')
```

Why the table is being locked?

P.S : No other person is running the code other than me & no one is accesing the database(DB2).

Comment: No one is running the _code_ besides you, but could other people be using the database?  Please let us know if that might be the case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, updated. No one is using the db, and no other developer or tester. Only me using the code and db

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, Im using DB2 and updated in the question too.

Comment: If the Db2 server is running on i-series (as/400), then follow the Recovery Text for SQL0913 at the documentation page https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_73/rzala/rzalaml.htm  in particular to determine from Db2 which locks are active. You may *think* you are the only statement running against the table, so it's better the verify your assumptions.

Comment: Side note: the direct concatenation is a vector for SQL Injection.  What you should be doing is creating a dynamic list of parameter markers and replacing them (for good practice, if nothing else).

Answer (score 1):

Where is `List<String> ids` comming from?

Assuming an SQL statement in another part of the code that accesses the same rows, then it's likely the source of your locks.

Include that code also...

Without it, some suggestions

- pass in the connection, so that the locks are within the same connection
- close the prior RS/connection first
- update the rows within the first statement